Reducing the negative runtime impact of eval/1
In ECLiPSe 7.1 using the IC library, I am trying to reduce the impact of eval/1.
My regression tests currently run in about 280 seconds without using eval/1 (because all the constraints are between plain variables and numbers).
As I expand my problem and start to construct constraints using IC involving expressions such as -X and X + Y in relational constraints I understand I must wrap my variables using eval/1 otherwise I get aborts with violations such as:
number expected in set_up_ic_con(2, _61357{[0, 1]}, [0 * 1, 1 * - 9.2233720368547758e+18, -1 * _59764{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}])
However, adding eval/1 everywhere as in
R #= (eval(Le) $>= eval(Ri)).
make my regression tests runtime (which don't need eval to run) jump from 280 seconds to 417 seconds (i.e. 50% slow down [Why is there such a performance hit when X and Y are either plain IC vars or numbers?]).
My question is how can I apply eval only when it might be needed to avoid the performance hit?
I have tried to modify what is sent to IC as follows:
my_eval(Le, Le_eval),
my_eval(Ri, Ri_eval),
R #= (Le_eval $>= Ri_eval).

with
my_eval(X, X) :-
    var(X),
    !.
my_eval(X, X) :-
    number(X),
    !.
my_eval(X, Y) :-
    eval(X, Y).   %leads to: instantiation fault in -(_44857{2147483647 .. 4294967295}, 4294967286, _106245)

or even
my_eval(X, eval(X)).    %leads to number expected in set_up_ic_con(2, _61549{[0, 1]}, [0 * 1, 1 * eval(- 9.2233720368547758e+18), -1 * _60045{-1.0Inf .. 1.0Inf}])

My best solution below is very ugly but brings down the run time to its original value:
    (compound(Ri) ->
        (compound(Le) ->
            R #= (eval(Le) $>= eval(Ri))
        ;
            R #= (Le $>= eval(Ri))
        )
    ;
        (compound(Le) ->
            R #= (eval(Le) $>= Ri)
        ;
            R #= (Le $>= Ri)
        )
    ).

Is there an alternative to the above? (PS contrary to the documentation of compound/1 (and therefore atomic/1), compound/1 is not the negation of atomic/1 as atomic(X) fails and compound(X) also fails)
